# Python class objects: how to avoid repeated calculations?

Tags: python, class, matrix

I want to ask for your suggestions on how to construct a Python class that best suits my needs.

Suppose I first introduce a Python class `LatticeClass`. In particular, the `LatticeClass` comes with a method `TheModel()` that can create a hermitian matrix `HH` as shown below:

```
obj = LatticeClass()
obj.a = 3.0
obj.b = -0.80
HH = obj.TheModel()
```

Now I want to introduce another Python class `LatticeProperty`, which is inherited from `LatticeClass`. This class will calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of `HH` and also use them to calculate something else. For example, here is the code I have written:

```
class LatticeProperty(LatticeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def spectrum(self):
        HH = self.TheModel()
        mat = HH.todense()
        print(mat.shape)
        val, vec = Lib.eig(mat)
        return val, vec

    def Method1(self):
        val, vec = self.spectrum
        total_energy = val.sum()
        return total_energy
```

Suppose I now write the following code:

```
newobj = LatticeProperty()
newobj.a = 3.0
newobj.b = -0.80
```

What I want are the following:

1. When I call `newobj.spectrum`, I can obtain just ask the system to give me the eigenvalues and eigenvectors without doing diagonalization again unless I change parameters `a` and `b`.
2. When I call `newobj.Method1()`, it should give me the final answer using the stored eigenvalues and eigenvectors, without invoking matrix diagonalization.

However, at this moment, the system carries out a matrix diagionalization every time I call `newobj.spectrum`. What should I do to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`@property`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)?

Comment: @0x5453 I tried to use @property, but I found that it still involves additional diagonalizations. For example, if I convert `Spectrum` to a property, the call obj.Spectrum takes 0.9 sec (one matrix diagonialization is involved). However, when I next call obj.Method1(), which just sums all eigenvalues, takes 0.87 sec. It seems that obj.Method1() also invokes a matrix diagonalization? If not, why a simple sum takes so long?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your full code.  How were you using `@property`?  I imagined giving `LatticeProperty.a` and `LatticeProperty.b` a custom `setter` to cache the diagonalization/eigenvalues/etc.

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks for your reply! I rephrased my question in the main text, and also appended my code to show how I use the ```@property``` method. I am looking forward to your reply. Thanks again!